# Difference of a field based on the first and last record of a month in DB2

Tags: db2

How to fetch the first and last row of records for each month and find difference of some other field on the same table. For example we have a table "READING" and we need to find the difference of READING based on (MAX(READINGDATE) - MIN(READINGDATE) for each month.

```
+------------------------------------------------+
+-ASSETNUM+------+READING+------+READINGDATE+----+
-  100            4500           2019-01-02
   100            2800           2019-01-03
   100            1400           2019-01-15
   100            800            2019-01-22
   100            3020           2019-01-29
   100            4800           2019-01-31
   100            2750           2019-02-01
   100            3580           2019-02-08
   100            768            2019-02-19
   100            1890           2019-02-28
```

The expected output should be as below

```
+-----------------------------------------+
+-ASSETNUM+-----+READING+----+READINGDATE-+
   100           300           Jan 2019
   100           -860          Feb 2019
```

The Reading date field is in DATETIME format . I understand we can do min and max of the data field however I'm not sure how to determine the difference of the first and last values for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
with READING (READING, READINGDATE) as 
(
values 
  (4500, timestamp('2019-01-02', '00.00.00'))
, (2800, timestamp('2019-01-03', '00.00.00'))
, (1400, timestamp('2019-01-15', '00.00.00'))
, ( 800, timestamp('2019-01-22', '00.00.00'))
, (3020, timestamp('2019-01-29', '00.00.00'))
, (4800, timestamp('2019-01-31', '00.00.00'))
, (2750, timestamp('2019-02-01', '00.00.00'))
, (3580, timestamp('2019-02-08', '00.00.00'))
, ( 768, timestamp('2019-02-19', '00.00.00'))
, (1890, timestamp('2019-02-28', '00.00.00'))
)
*/
select mx.READING - mn.READING as READING, g.READINGDATE_MONTH
from 
(
select 
  to_char(READINGDATE, 'Mon YYYY', 'en_US') READINGDATE_MONTH
, year(READINGDATE) READINGDATE_Y
, month(READINGDATE) READINGDATE_M
, min(READINGDATE) as READINGDATE_MIN
, max(READINGDATE) as READINGDATE_MAX
from READING
group by to_char(READINGDATE, 'Mon YYYY', 'en_US'), year(READINGDATE), month(READINGDATE)
) g
join READING mn on mn.READINGDATE = g.READINGDATE_MIN
join READING mx on mx.READINGDATE = g.READINGDATE_MAX
order by g.READINGDATE_Y, g.READINGDATE_M
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use analytic functions `first_value()` and `last_value()`:

```
select distinct 
  assetnum, 
  last_value(reading) 
    over (partition by ASSETNUM, month(readingdate) 
          order by readingdate
          range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
- first_value(reading) 
    over (partition by ASSETNUM, month(readingdate) 
          order by readingdate
          range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following),
  varchar_format(readingdate, 'Mon YYYY')
from readings
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c53de069b9edf12dc0fd00825372855a)